Problem in exporting graphs in OriginLab 2018
Every time i try to export my origin graphs this error pops up:
OIMGLT95_64.DLL
Error 14001
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
The dialog box never opens up. It just shows this error every time. Please somebody help me rectify this.
I tried almost everything. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software several times. Tried downloading and installing relevant Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables but nothing works.
